# Regex for capturing values in a delimited list

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to write a regex that will extract clean values from a delimited list. The catch is that the list could be delimited by different symbols or words. The captured values will be trimmed in the code, so spaces don't matter.

Input:

```
English (UK), French* , German and Polish  & Russian; Portugese and Italian
```

Regex I have so far:

```
\A(?:(?<Value>[^,;&*]+)[,;&\s*]*)*\Z
```

The delimiters I'm expecting are `,;&`. I included the `*` because I want it excluded from the captured value.

Captured values:

```
English (UK), French, German and Polish, Russian, Portugese and Italian
```

Expected values:

```
English (UK), French, German, Polish, Russian, Portugese, Italian
```

The problem I have is that I can't get `and` to be treated as a delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not necessary to use Regex here:

```
    string str = "English (UK), French* , German and Polish  & Russian; Portugese and Italian";
    string[] results = str.Split(new string[] { ",", ";", "&", "*" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    foreach (string s in results)
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
            Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Comment: Why not add the `"and"` to the `new string[]{...}`?

Comment: Will go with this solution for this problem. It's miles faster than regexes. I've seen the light. I'm going to use  `",", ";", "&", "*", " and "`, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with:

```
\A(?:(?<Value>(?:[^,;&*\s]|\s(?!and))+)(?:(?:and|[,;&\s*])*))*\Z
```

**Explanation:**

`(?:...)` is a non-capturing group, not changing the match, just not storing the result in a group.

`(?!...)` is negative lookahead, matching if the characters following don't match the given pattern.

Basically this only matches white-space as part of `Value` if "and" doesn't follow it, and it includes "and" in the separator.

This seems awfully complicated, you may want replace `" and "` with a separator and use your current expression.

[Test](http://www.rubular.com/r/egjC1vyERC).

Comment: Thanks for the regex. It works correctly, but I've decided that I don't need a regex to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Or just do this to your current result:

```
desiredResult = currentResult.Replace("and", ",");
```

Comment: I thought about it and I don't want to do that. Plus that replace will replace more than I would want it to. `Replace(" and ", ", ")` would have been better.